# Proper way to end an instance of a class?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my Android app, I have a class that extends `Thread` that runs when there's an established internet connection (3G/WIFI).

When the app is loaded, if an internet connection is established, I instantiate the class like this:

```
 MyThread thread = new MyThread(); //  (it calls its own start() method)
```

In the thread, if the connection is lost, I want to destroy the `Thread`. I was told not to run `finalize()`, how would I destroy it so that `thread == null` is true?

---

Edit: The reason I was asking was, later on, I would like to restart the thread in case connectivity returned, and a check to see if `(thread == null)` would have been easy.  I could just use a flag to indicate the thread needs to be restarted or check to see if it was interrupted.  Thanks for the helpful comments so far.

Comment: Just return from your thread, the garbage collector will take care of it

Comment: when connection is lost, call `interrupt()` on your Thread.

Comment: create a flag and set it to true when your thread is running. When you wish to stop simply set it to false. This way you can be sure that the thread will not continue to run in the background. leave it for garbage collector.

Comment: Keep in mind, nothing will set `thread` to `null` for you. If you need it to be `null` when the thread dies, that is something you need to handle, and garbage collection will not dispose of the thread (even if terminated) as long as `thread` points to it.

Comment: You could simply not destroy the thread?  It can itself retry connectivity and signal if it returns.  Multithreading rule 7 - if there is any way at all to avoid needing to terminate/destroy threads once started, take it.  No GC, no abiguity as to whether the thread exists or not, no dodgy termination code, no booleans, no polling of stop flags, no hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you don't subclass `Thread`. You create a `Runnable`, and pass it into a `Thread` object, or better yet, an `ExecutorService`.

But you don't have to worry about cleaning up after the thread is done, it will be handled automatically by the garbage collector. If you want your own local reference to be null, just null it out yourself, or better yet, don't hang on to it.

```
new Thread( new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // put your stuff here
    }
} ).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

1. A `thread of execution will live until it has finished executing its run() method`, then 
   it either moves to the `dead stat`e or in the `thread pool`.
2. Its always better to control the `run()` method using a`boolean variable`.

   eg:

   ```
      boolean isRunning = true;

      new Thread(new Runnable()

          {

      public void run()

         {

        while(isRunning)

            {

             // Keep doing your work here....

                  if (!isRunning){

                           break;
                       }


                 }

     }
   ```

   `}).start();`

Comment: Note that synchronization is needed for the boolean flag to ensure visibility in both threads.